# How do I get HTTP_ORIGIN in javascript?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I'm aware you can get the referrer in Javascript runtime in a browser with `document.referrer`... but how do get the **HTTP_ORIGIN** that I see passed in the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/origin

Looks like Chrome is the only browser that lets you get that.